# Is there a statsmodel formula equivalent of the R glm library for y ~ .?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a dataframe containing the following columns:

> y as the dependent variable
> A, B, C, D, E, F as the independent variables.

I want to make a regression using the statsmodels module and I don't want to express the formula argument as follows:

```
formula = 'y ~ A + B + C + D + E + F'
```

R glm library does have a simplification by expressing **formula = y ~ .**

I was wondering if statsmodel shortcut as there is one for the glm library in R.

P.S.: the actual dataframe that I'm working has 27 variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut like "." in patsy formula handling which is used by statsmodels.

However, python string manipulation is simple.

An example that I'm currently using,
`DATA` is my dataframe, `docvis` is the outcome variable, and I have a constant column that is not needed in the formula.

```
formula = "docvis ~ " + " + ".join([i for i in DATA if i not in ["docvis", "const"]])
formula
'docvis ~ offer + ssiratio + age + educyr + physician + nonphysician + medicaid + private + female + phylim + actlim + income + totchr + insured + age2 + linc + bh + ldocvis + ldocvisa + docbin + aget + aget2 + incomet'
```

More explicit would be to use column names directly `DATA.columns`.

In modern Python we don't need to build the list in the list comprehension, and we can use

`formula = "docvis ~ " + " + ".join(i for i in DATA.columns if i not in ["docvis", "const"])`